# psql.exe - password authentication failed in windows

Tags: postgresql

I'm a noob in PostgreSQL. I installed ver 9.2 on windows7. During installation it asked for password and i entered it.
Now whenever i run d:\tools\PostgreSQL9.2\bin\psql.exe it asks for password. When i enter the password it doesn't accept and
it shows "password authentication failed for user "user1". I have re-installed twice already. Also i tried entering my system 
password.

I'm trying to get the below command to work

```
psql.exe -f db/codedb.sql development
```

What should i do to get this working ?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try setting the user name when connecting.

```
psql.exe -U username -d dbname -f somefile.sql
```

You've probably set up the default "postgres" user during installation. Not sure if you've created any others.

To add other users and databases just connect to as postgres to the postgres database and do something like:

```
CREATE USER myuser WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'secret';
CREATE DATABASE mydb OWNER myuser;
```

If your machine is secure you might also like to set up a [password file](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/libpq-pgpass.html)

Comment: thanks, but i get a warning message : "extra command line arguement somefile.sql ignored" 
due to this the sql file is not imported

Comment: If there are spaces in any of the parameters you'll need to quote them "like this", otherwise it should work just fine.

Comment: i tried psql.exe -U postgres -d development "d:\myprojects\ruby\HelloWorld\db\data.sql" still got the message ignored the extra command line parameter...

Comment: Why did you leave the "-f" out?

Comment: Hi @RichardHuxton thanks for your comment. You can use psql without ".exe", "psql -U username -d database etc...." command will work fine.

Answer (score 15):

change  "trust" instead of "md5" in the pg_hba.conf to connect to the database  and change your password.

```
    --------------------configuration in pg_hba.conf---------------
    local   all         all                               trust  
    local   all         postgres                          trust          
    host    all         all         ::1/128               trust
```

Comment: Keep in mind that changing only the IPv4 might not work, you should change both IPv4 and IPv6 as the answer suggests

Answer (score 2):

Here is the simple solution for installation Postgresql without getting errors(cluster errors and authentication errors),i have followed below steps and i got installed postgresql sucessfully

1. create new user in windows from controlpanel-->user accounts
2. After logged into new user(whic u hve created) copy postrgresql(.exe) application into any directory(other than 'C') and click on the application to install(dont forget to change the installation directory to which u have copied the application file above).
3. after completion of installaion change below configurations in postgresql.conf and pg_hba.cof

add like below in your `postgresql.conf`

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

add like below in your `pg_hba.cof`

```
# IPv4 local connections:
host     all     all     127.0.0.1/32    trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host     all     all     ::1/128     trust
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
# host   sameuser    postgres    127.0.0.1/32    trust
#host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 md5
```