# PostgreSQL on Windows: is there a default password?

Tags: windows, postgresql

Just installed PostgreSQL on Windows7. I was not asked to set a password during installation. When I run psql, I'm asked for a password. Googled some and the only possible default password was "postgre". But that didn't work. Also tried a blank password and my Windows password. Neither of them worked. Read some advanced stuff how to reset a password, but this can't be right? What am I missing here? What password am I supposed to enter?

Comment: Any installer since version 8.0 asked you for a password. Prior to version 9.2 you were asked for two password: one for the postgres database user and one for the Windows service user.

Comment: The problem is that the default username for `psql` is `Administrator` and if you followed the installer then you only created a password for user `postgres`, so the solution is to run `psql -Upostgres` which specifies the user `postgres`

Comment: check out this:     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12562928/psql-exe-password-authentication-failed-in-windows

Comment: You are asked to create a user name and password, but by default PostgreSQL will try to connect to the cluster created at install time as postgres

Comment: Mine was: username: postgres  password: 1234

Comment: Similar question and answer: https://superuser.com/questions/576623/default-password-for-postgresql

Answer (score 14):

Try this:

```
Open PgAdmin -> Files -> Open pgpass.conf
```

You would get the path of `pgpass.conf` at the bottom of the window.
Go to that location and open this file, you can find your password there.

[Reference](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/libpq-pgpass.html)

If the above does not work, you may consider trying this:

1. Edit `pg_hba.conf` to allow trust authorization temporarily
2. Reload the config file (`pg_ctl reload`)
3. Connect and issue `ALTER ROLE / PASSWORD` to set the new password
4. Edit `pg_hba.conf` again and restore the previous settings
5. Reload the config file again

Comment: The file is empty. Should I type it in manually?

Comment: user : postgres, pwd: password

Comment: For me in pgAdmin4 username : postgres and password : postgres worked out.. Leaving here in case it helps anyone else.

Comment: @Sri9911 the same worked for me