# Connection to postgresql failed

Tags: postgresql, windows-10

I downloaded postgresql and pgAdmin on Windows 10.  As soon as I open pgAdmin I get a connection failed error when trying to connect to the default database (PostgreSQL 9.6). I opened this port in my firewall but it didn't fix it.

[image]

This is the end of my pg_hba.conf file:

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                peer

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#local   replication     postgres                                peer
#host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            md5
#host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 md5
```

According to currports, 5432 is not listed, so perhaps opening it on the firewall didn't actually open it.

Comment: Have you checked the `pg_hba.conf` file inside your datadir? Probably it is not allowing network connections. If needed, check the docs for more information about this file: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html

Comment: hmm, I changed all those to `trust` and it still didn't do it.

Comment: You can look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18698889/postgresql-windows-is-there-a-default-password

Comment: Could you add your file to the question, please? Also, check with a small utility called CurrPorts ( http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/cports.html ) if the port 5432 is open. Please, add all this info to your question.

Comment: @Vinícius Gobbo A. de Oliveira I updated it.  The port is actually not listed on CurrPorts

Comment: Looks like you are missing a `listen_address = '*'` in your `postgresql.conf` (actually, a think this is the default, at last for the 127.0.0.1, so I'm not really sure this really is the problem). Please, double check your firewall.

Comment: Well, I added two rules for port 5432, once for TCP and once for UDP and it still appears to be closed on all the tests I have done.